# getting connection was interrupted for uploading files bigger than 4 MB

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ms-word

I'm developing some website with ASP.Net for uploading and processing some MS word docs.  and I get connection was interrupted in Chrome or connection was reset in firefox for uploading docs bigger than 4 MB. I get this error as soon as I push the button and it almost upload nothing.

it's the part of the code I think causes the error (I use the common input type=file for upload slot)

```
 if (filMyFile.PostedFile != null)
    {
        // Get a reference to PostedFile object
        HttpPostedFile myFile = filMyFile.PostedFile;

        // Get size of uploaded file
        int nFileLen = myFile.ContentLength;

        // make sure the size of the file is > 0
        if (nFileLen > 0)
        {
            // Allocate a buffer for reading of the file
            byte[] myData = new byte[nFileLen];

            // Read uploaded file from the Stream
            myFile.InputStream.Read(myData, 0, nFileLen);

            // Create a name for the file to store
            string strFilename = Path.GetFileName(myFile.FileName);



            // Write data into a file
            WriteToFile(Server.MapPath(strFilename), ref myData);
```

where do you think the problem is? thanks

Comment: It is likely to be the IIS setup (or perhaps firewall/loadbalancer in front of IIS) - because you get the error fast. It could also be the ASP .NET MaxRequestLength setting, but then you should see an exception in your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4MB is default limit set in machine.config. You can extend upload file limit by adding [`<httpRuntime/>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) element in web.config file. For more detail read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx) post.